# Impact on mortgage offer of changing interest rates in the UK

Tags: united-kingdom, mortgage

I live in the UK and my partner and I are about to buy a house. We have a mortgage in principle from a bank, which indicates the mortgage rate (fixed 5 years). We have just started doing all the paperwork, so we haven't signed yet the mortgage (which only happens after the surveys are done, I think) but there are rumours that interest rates are going to rise on November 1st.

How would this affect my mortgage offer? Could the bank change their offer?

Comment: Would it be a problem if the bank changed their offer? If a small interest rate rise would make your mortgage unaffordable, you probably shouldn't be taking it out.

Comment: @AakashM ahah good point. No, it wouldn't be unaffordable, don't worry. It would just give even more money to the bank for 5 years, for maybe a few days of difference, which is a shame. After asking my question, I learned banks give a day warning to brokers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The offer should have an expiry date somewhere in the small print, and it’s valid until that date, whatever the Bank of England may announce on November the 2nd (not the 1st). Unless the small print also specifies that the interest rate is linked to the Bank of England official bank rate, which is unlikely for a fixed-rate mortgage offer.

Comment: The offer only says "This is not a legally binding mortgage offer and it does not oblige XXX to provide you with the mortgage described in this illustration.", which could simply mean "once we've checked you and the house, we will offer you this", or not. Nothing mentioned about the Bank of England, so I assume we should be on that rate if everything works well. Thanks!

Comment: @Tobias OK, you said in your question that it was a mortgage offer. If it’s _not_ a mortgage offer then they _can_ withdraw or change it at any time, and might do so if the bank base rate increases, though they probably won’t since an increase is already factored in to future interest rate expectations.

Comment: Hum, I assumed it was an offer that was passed through the broker. Good to know though, thanks!